biblatex citations behaviour with ambiguous author name
I have the following document:
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\parencite{Doe1}, \parencite{Doe2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

With the corresponding bibliography.bib file:
@Article{Doe1,
author={Doe, John
and Doe, Jane
and Muller, Max},
title={Important research},
journal={Journal of Science},
year={2024},
}
@Article{Doe2,
author={Doe, John
and Doe, Jane
and Foo, Bar},
title={Important research 2},
journal={Journal of Science},
year={2024},
}

The output I get is:

1 Introduction (Doe, Doe, and Muller 2024), (Doe, Doe, and Foo 2024)

However, I want to change it to this:

1 Introduction (Doe 2024b), (Doe 2024a)

I tried multiple combinations of settings like:
\RequirePackage[style=apa, maxcitenames=1, uniquename=false, uniquelist=minyear, autocite=inline,backend=biber]{biblatex}

which did not work.
I got closer to the desired result by manually adding a
shortauthor={Doe, John},

to all entries in the BibTeX file.
However, that is not a good approach for me since I have 300+ reference and the output is still not good, I get

1 Introduction (Doe et al. [Doe], 2024b), (Doe, J., 2024a)

Is there some way/setting to achieve the desired result?
Since I have to work with a template, I cannot change to natbib and \citep or other commands if this is relevant.

I think it should be enough the uniquelist=false option.
Maybe, you would like also to remove the comma and the andothers string.
So, if I gather correctly, to customise the punctuation, you have to customise the \nameyeardelim punctuation: try something like that.
\renewcommand{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

To hide the andothers string from the citations, I think it's enough to modify the name:andothers bibmacro and adding a third test: \ifbibliography.
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}%
                and
                test {\ifmorenames}%
                and
                test {\ifbibliography}}%
        {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
            {\finalandcomma}
            {}%
        \printdelim{andothersdelim}\bibstring{andothers}}
        {}}

If you would completely remove the string, clean the bibmacro.
I give you back a MWEB.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa,uniquelist=false]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
    @article{Doe1,
        author={Doe, John and Doe, Jane
        and Muller, Max},
        title={Important research},
        journal={Journal of Science},
        year={2023}}
    @article{Doe2,
        author={Doe, John and Doe, Jane
        and Foo, Bar},
        title={Important research 2},
        journal={Journal of Science},
        year={2023}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\renewcommand{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}%
                and
                test {\ifmorenames}%
                and
                test {\ifbibliography}}%
        {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
            {\finalandcomma}
            {}%
        \printdelim{andothersdelim}\bibstring{andothers}}
        {}}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\parencite{Doe1}, \parencite{Doe2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

